# Android Studio - UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, exception, android-studio

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, or have done wrong to debug my app. Can anyone give me an idea of how to fix this?

I deleted all the libraries and reinstalled them, and I've worked out that it's an issue with the Google Repository. But I don't know what to do. Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

`Error:Execution failed for task ':SecuriHUB:dexDebug'.`

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio1\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --output C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\dex\debug C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\classes\debug C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\avcodec-a23ce361a09c930e68fee244ef4b9f70b8df1da4.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\avcodec-bab13459b97dce683c98960d6342d99522af142f.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\avutil-52522a8339be7c888d2262803acf07db17ec6aa2.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\avutil-6a389e589f441392b5746bb77bf970e260c15ac8.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-2b5def6b4c7c7ce682519b9b0443fe04a26c0919.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-2f5552383b37e78f4ec718f853bc1b1e1ec317a2.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-42b726da5c048a82a08e89a4b70c184b94608aa0.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-6e01a35945fee3c0661a964108bc1f436ada1652.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-76fa51ae23d8bf77e8657dce65fcc7cf5b61044d.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-96196602ae75c43f247b5c746cd935d656b8b543.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-9b73bafe39f49c24dfc02321659c168a6d30c9b9.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-cae5aaa06f449bff8bee4372de96fa33783e31ee.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-ee9ef6ddaaef0705b573495d987a8ea074f0bc0a.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-fe7b9a83f65f77ec6904839666546d97f8c5c435.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\commons-io-1.3.2-76b40519b6d96123e0fafc55a0437071960ae683.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\commons-io-1.3.2-e23cc4dead7a42abc070337b6602255ca7a78ff3.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\GSSc-3ac0bc0f497991728bf7e0dc89da2dc1425604d1.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\GSSc-577c0e7d97895f2804faa5f54f1999124502db90.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\httpclientandroidlib-1.1.2-2caa8f5d76aec2bd9d92323cc8b178d8d67f6081.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\httpclientandroidlib-1.1.2-ec8f9ce27a72b4bf5d7cf1b5784c45f09b73caa0.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-20.0.0-45e7f39ff8ef841d2b829e696be46453d466481b.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-20.0.0-565a411117f2b6f68963042a0d52ec0b2b843b4d.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\json-1.0.0-0722a5a7126e9051d1bd542a6af3e6bc94116d50.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\json-1.0.0-2f404cb0d63823de6ac84000bf670564809870b7.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\redmine-java-api-1.23.1-25bdd461e5cb7eb722db4cdfb2f55f44c1df1fe6.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\redmine-java-api-1.23.1-e491ee895bc5f5e09d8af0b4db6f552cda256ca5.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\slf4j-api-1.7.1-2329e6fbcf26dbe6aed9bd7c2820b4ceaae23de6.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\slf4j-api-1.7.1-b7cd7d60262580384ff9b076e0244ef18212f212.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-20.0.0-1514e8d1e5d6b1f7784080d9e0002766205e8fd5.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-20.0.0-d005872198788c93ef85f437377c5a4608557980.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\swscale-d2110a412161ef1a3b43b811bf48cb6ca2a64c61.jar C:\Mezzo\Koren\mezzo\SecuriHUB\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\swscale-e5534023e6b3b892096f3ad4fd09226e3317701d.jar
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/BuildConfig;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how I fixed this, but I did.

I had to reinstall the sdk and the libraries again, and make sure that in the build.gradle it had minimum sdk of 11 or something.

But hey, who am I to complain... IT WORKS NOW WOO!